# Pagination script needed to be put on view page of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

CI developers my requirement is:

I want to put pagination script which will work on my view page i.e on my result page.

```
$per_page=$this->input->post('per_page');
$look = $this->input->post('look');
$age = $this->input->post('age'); 
$age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
$age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
$se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
$subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
$coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
$sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
$ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
$qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');
$data['showdata']=$this->searchresultss->login($per_page,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);

$this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
```

**Below is my model:**

```
public function login ($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
{
    $query="SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE  

        if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
        AND
        IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
        AND 
        if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
        AND  
        if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
        AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
        AND state LIKE  '%%'
        AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
        AND age >=  '$age_from'
        AND age <=  '$age_to'
        AND 
        IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
        And gender = '$look'
        And status='1'";

    $data=array();
    $query=$this->db->query($query);
    $data['results']=$query->result_array();
    $data['count']=$query->num_rows();

    $data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3);

    return $data;
}
```

**Below is my result page i.e view page**

```
<?php

if (isset($showdata)){
    foreach ($showdata['results'] as $k => $v) {
?>
        <?php echo $v['gender']; echo $v['email'];?>
<?php
    }
}

echo $showdata['count'];  echo $showdata['pages'];
?>
```

Here starts my question I'm posting complete controller, model, view o/p what I did and I want some one who can help me in editing my model, controllere, view which can show the result in pagination.

I'm completely new CI, so I request all CI guys to help me in pagination script if required you can completely edit my model,controller,and view.

I will be thankful for those who can help me.

Comment: You should not expect ANYTHING from us. We are here to show you in the right direction, not to raise at your expectations. And please remove the code formatting from your text. Only code should be in `code format`.

Comment: And you should learn to format your question better. If you want someone to put an effort for you, you should put some for yourself first

Comment: What you said is right iam trying sice 3 days but i failed so i posted my question in brief.I edited what you said mr machineaddict.

Comment: Vicky, there are still normal question text formatted as code. Please take a few minutes to correct that. When you save, _look_ at the question to see if it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Are you passing anything else in to the controller method? What is the name of the controller method? What is the url for this page?

Comment: controller name is searchresult

Comment: no iam not passing anything else

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function users($offset = 0)
{

    $this->load->library('session');
    if ($postdata = $this->session->flashdata('post_data')) {

        foreach (unserialize($postdata) as $key => $value) {
            $_POST[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_data', serialize($this->input->post()));

    $data = array();

    $limit = $this->input->post('per_page');
    $look = $this->input->post('look');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
    $age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
    $se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
    $subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
    $coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
    $sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
    $ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
    $qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');

    $results = $this->searchresultss->login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);

    //for base_url()
    $this->load->helper('url');

    //Pagination Config
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url("searchresults/users/");
    $config['total_rows'] = count($results);
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;

    $this->load->library('pagination', $config);
    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    //Reducing the number of results for the view
    /** NOTE: This is not the most efficient way **/
    $data['results'] = array_slice($results, $offset, $limit);


    $this->load->view('searchresult', $data);
}
```

I understand this is just a question and you may not have put all of your code in here, but incase you have, you really need to look at using form validation as this code is potentially very vulnerable!

**Model**

```
public function login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification)
{

        return $this->db->query("SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE  
        if('$se_ct'!='', sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
        AND
        IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
        AND 
        if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
        AND  
        if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
        AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
        AND state LIKE  '%%'
        AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
        AND age >=  '$age_from'
        AND age <=  '$age_to'
        AND 
        IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
        And gender = '$look'
        And status='1'")->result();
}
```

Depending on how many potential rows this could produce I would consider adding another method which counts the rows, then you can use use `LIMIT` in your SQL query in the above model.

**View**

```
<?php
echo $pagination_links;

if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Results set is empty';
} else {


    /**
     * The code between the "testing comment can be removed, however, use it to check that you are typing the parameter names corrent (remember it is case-sensitive)" 
     * Remove the code between the "Testing" comments when you're happy.
     */


    //Testing
    echo '<pre>';
    echo var_dump($results);
    echo '</pre><br /><br />';
    //Testing End


    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result->email.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i completely copy controller iam getting emty array and not getting any output

Comment: Ross ...till now you have spend lot of time for me ..so request you to spend some more time

Comment: Have you changed the name of the method to users?

Comment: In that case I don't know why that isn't working. Google how to turn error logging on and see where the issue is.

Comment: $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;  have we forgot to use this Ross//

Comment: You shouldn't need it.

Comment: my laptop got down bcos of over heat..Iwl be back after an hour

Comment: Vicky, this site is not meant for people to come on have code done for them (I will from time-to-time, but I shouldn't). Check that the controller is being called (correct url), using var_dump() 1) Check that you post array is populated and that everything is there that should be. 2) Check the query still works. 3) Check the data array in the controller has everything it needs to. Also, use google and find out how to get your errors switched on.

Comment: and more thing when i select numeric 2 the url changing to http://localhost/kkci/searchresult/users/1 instead it should be http://localhost/kkci/searchresult/users/2  ...i think what iam saying is right

Comment: No, one is correct in this case as the array should start at 0. Also, have you set an encryption key in **application/config/config.php**? If not set one.

Comment: Ross life  saver ..R u there

Comment: Have you set the encryption key in the config file and have you sorted your error messaging out yet?

Comment: i have set encryption key

Comment: Ok, and have you sorted you PHP error messaging out?

Comment: no not yet ..iam trying ..can you explain how to set error message

Comment: Are you using Windows (WAMP or MAMP beta), Mac (MAMP) and Linux?

Comment: Quick fix: go index.php in the **root** of your codeigniter project, find `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and underneath it put `ini_set('display_errors','On');`. This should put the errors directly into the page. Proper fix: Next, google: "xampp php error logs".

Comment: i did has you said .i added ini_set('display_errors','On'); in below line of error_reporting(E_ALL); of index.php now i wl google

Comment: Find a way to make sure they are switched on, and find out where the error log is stored so you can open it a see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yes they are switched on  and i could find out the error log file is stored there are no errors